# How to display notification pop-up bubble numbers like Facebook notification icon in JSF page?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

In my project there is a requirement that I have to display the notifications pop-up numbers on some string names. Like Facebook notification icons. If notifications increase the pop-up bubble number also dynamically increases. Like this way I want to display bubble numbers on some letters in JSF. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Primefaces `<p:poll/>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf).

Comment: How about simply adding CSS to the `<p:outputText/>` component?